# Python generator's 'yield' in separate function

Tags: python, google-app-engine, generator

I'm implementing a utility library which is a sort-of task manager intended to run within the distributed environment of Google App Engine cloud computing service. (It uses a combination of task queues and memcache to execute background processing). I plan to use generators to control the execution of tasks, essentially enforcing a non-preemptive "concurrency" via the use of `yield` in the user's code.

The trivial example - processing a bunch of database entities - could be something like the following:

```
class EntityWorker(Worker):
    def setup():
        self.entity_query = Entity.all()
    def run():
        for e in self.entity_query:
            do_something_with(e)
            yield
```

As we know, `yield` is two way communication channel, allowing to pass values to code that uses generators. This allows to simulate a "preemptive API" such as the `SLEEP` call below:

```
def run():
    for e in self.entity_query:
        do_something_with(e)
        yield Worker.SLEEP, timedelta(seconds=1)
```

But this is ugly. It would be great to hide the `yield` within seperate function which could invoked in simple way:

```
self.sleep(timedelta(seconds=1))
```

The problem is that putting `yield` in function `sleep` turns **it** into a generator function. The call above would therefore just return another generator. Only after adding `.next()` and `yield` back again we would obtain previous result:

```
yield self.sleep(timedelta(seconds=1)).next()
```

which is of course even more ugly and unnecessarily verbose that before.

Hence my question: Is there a way to put `yield` into function without turning it into generator function but making it usable by other generators to yield values computed by it?

Comment: `yield` makes a function a generator -- if it's not in `self.run`, `run` is not a generator, if it's in `self.sleep`, `sleep` is a generator. That's how you define a generator in Python. So your question becomes "How do I make a generator that isn't a generator" or "How do I not make a generator into a generator" -- neither of those make sense.

Comment: Another solution would be to make your own iterable object rather than use a generator. It'd be more work, though, and probably not justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, this won't work. But a "middle-way" could be fine:

```
def sleepjob(*a, **k):
    if a:
        return Worker.SLEEP, a[0]
    else:
        return Worker.SLEEP, timedelta(**k)
```

So

```
yield self.sleepjob(timedelta(seconds=1))
yield self.sleepjob(seconds=1)
```

looks ok for me.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing the obvious:

```
class EntityWorker(Worker):
    def setup(self):
        self.entity_query = Entity.all()

    def run(self):
        for e in self.entity_query:
            do_something_with(e)
            yield self.sleep(timedelta(seconds=1))

    def sleep(self, wait):
        return Worker.SLEEP, wait
```

It's the `yield` that turns functions into generators, it's impossible to leave it out.

To hide the yield you need a higher order function, in your example it's `map`:

```
from itertools import imap

def slowmap(f, sleep, *iters):
    for row in imap(f, self.entity_query):
        yield Worker.SLEEP, wait

def run():
    return slowmap(do_something_with, 
                   (Worker.SLEEP, timedelta(seconds=1)),
                   self.entity_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a look at the [ndb](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/). It uses generators as co-routines (as you are proposing here), allowing you to write programs that work with rpcs asynchronously.

The api does this by wrapping the generator with another function that 'primes' the generator (it calls .next() immediately so that the code begins execution). The tasklets are also designed to work with App Engine's rpc infrastructure, making it possible to use any of the existing asynchronous api calls.

With the concurreny model used in ndb, you `yield` either a future object (similar to what is described in pep-3148) or an App Engine rpc object. When that rpc has completed, the execution in the function that yielded the object is allowed to continue.

If you are using a model derived from `ndb.model.Model` then the following will allow you to asynchronously iterate over a query:

```
from ndb import tasklets

@tasklets.tasklet
def run():
it = iter(Entity.query())
# Other tasklets will be allowed to run if the next call has to wait for an rpc.
while (yield it.has_next_async()):
  entity = it.next()
  do_something_with(entity)
```

Although ndb is still considered experimental (some of its error handling code still needs some work), I would recommend you have a look at it. I have used it in my last 2 projects and found it to be an excellent library.

Make sure you read through the documentation linked from the main page, and also the companion documentation for the [tasklet stuff](https://docs.google.com/a/tsukasa.net.au/document/d/1rPyB2RmRERAZDPpqy2cxzXeDGyfLhX-s-3dFVpnwFXw/view).